# Can we have a content containing Default Value + Binding Data?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I would like to know if there is any possibility in WPF to perform something like this :

```
<Label Content="ValueWhoNeverChange + {Binding MyTargetValue}"/>
```

Comment: There is no `+` operator in XAML if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate two strings, or add two numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is no `+` operator supported in XAML so if you want to display the sum of `ValueWhoNeverChange` and `MyTargetValue`, you will have to write some code.

You could either define a read-only property that returns the sum and bind to this one:

```
public int Sum => ValueWhoNeverChange + MyTargetValue;
```

Remember to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Sum` property whenever `MyTargetValue` is set to a new value.

Or you could use a converter: http://www.codearsenal.net/2013/12/wpf-multibinding-example.html#.XMBnQ0xuJaQ

```
<Label>
    <Label.Content>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <local:MultiC />
            </MultiBinding.Converter>
            <Binding Path="ValueWhoNeverChange" />
            <Binding Path="MyTargetValue" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

By the way, you should use a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label` to display text in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ContentStringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat?view=netframework-4.8) property, something like

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=MyTargetValue}"
    ContentStringFormat="ValueWhoNeverChange {0}" />
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: there is a ContentStringFormat equivalent for TextBlock ?

Comment: No there isn't. You have to use the [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat?view=netframework-4.8) property of your `Binding`.